# Compile-time efficient n-ary cartesian product of parameter packs with a transformation

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20, template-meta-programming, cartesian-product

In a previous question, solutions were given on how to compute the n-ary cartesian product of parameter packs (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71760742/882932), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59409722/882932) (and [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/217452/20652) but for tuples)). Basically, we consider the following wrapper:

```
template <class... Types>
struct pack {};

template <class... Packs>
struct pack_product {/* SOMETHING */}

template <class... Packs>
using pack_product_t = typename pack_product<Packs...>::type;
```

such that `pack_product_t<pack<A0, A1>, pack<B0, B1, B2>, pack<C0, C1>>` produces the following:

```
pack<
    pack<A0, B0, C0>, pack<A0, B0, C1>, 
    pack<A0, B1, C0>, pack<A0, B1, C1>,
    pack<A0, B2, C0>, pack<A0, B2, C1>, 
    pack<A1, B0, C0>, pack<A1, B0, C1>, 
    pack<A1, B1, C0>, pack<A1, B1, C1>,
    pack<A1, B2, C0>, pack<A1, B2, C1>, 
>;
```

(again see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71760742/882932) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59409722/882932) for solutions, even if I think they do not fully work when one of the input packs is the empty pack `pack<>`). This corresponds to the n-ary cartesian product of sets A×B×C={(a0, b0, c0), ..., (a1, b2, c1)} (set of tuples from a set-theoretic standpoint).

As an important note, one of the tricky part was to produce just two levels of packs, and not n-nested packs in the result (as in `pack<pack<pack<A0, B0>, C0>>, ...>`).

---

Now, what I would like to do is the combination of the n-ary cartesian product:

```
template <template <class> class Function, class... Packs>
struct pack_product_apply {
    using type = /* SOMETHING */
};

template <template <class> class Function, class... Packs>
using pack_product_apply_t = typename pack_product_apply<Function, Packs...>::type;
```

which basically computes:

```
pack<
    typename Function<pack<A0, B0, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A0, B0, C1>>::type, 
    typename Function<pack<A0, B1, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A0, B1, C1>>::type,
    typename Function<pack<A0, B2, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A0, B2, C1>>::type, 
    typename Function<pack<A1, B0, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A1, B0, C1>>::type, 
    typename Function<pack<A1, B1, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A1, B1, C1>>::type,
    typename Function<pack<A1, B2, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A1, B2, C1>>::type, 
>;
```

and just skips the elements which do not compile thanks to SFINAE: for example if the versions with B1 do not provide a valid `::type` the result would just be:

```
pack<
    typename Function<pack<A0, B0, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A0, B0, C1>>::type, 
    typename Function<pack<A0, B2, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A0, B2, C1>>::type, 
    typename Function<pack<A1, B0, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A1, B0, C1>>::type, 
    typename Function<pack<A1, B2, C0>>::type, typename Function<pack<A1, B2, C1>>::type, 
>;
```

And example of input type function would be:

```
template <class Pack> 
struct my_type_function;

template <class... Types> 
struct my_type_function<pack<Types...>>: std::common_type<Types...> {};
```

---

Computing the cartesian product first and applying the function after on its result is a no-brainer. But I have the feeling (but I may be wrong) that it would be suboptimal from the compiler standpoint.

**QUESTION:** How to implement `pack_product_apply` in a compiler-efficient way where the type function would be applied "on-the-fly" when computing each element of the product instead of computing all the element first and then applying the function?

Comment: So the question is how to do cartesian product but substituting the pack type with a provided meta function?

Comment: Yes, with the result of the provided function (when it compiles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works with O(1) instantiation depth

```
template<template<typename...> class F, int N, typename...>
struct fn_typelist {};

template<typename...>
struct typelist {};

template<template<typename...> class F, int N, typename... Ts>
typelist<fn_typelist<F, N, Ts>...> layered(typelist<Ts...>);

template<template<typename...> class F, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
auto operator+(fn_typelist<F, sizeof...(Ts) + sizeof...(Us), Ts...>&&,
               fn_typelist<F, sizeof...(Ts) + sizeof...(Us), Us...>&&)
    -> F<Ts..., Us...>;

template<template<typename...> class F, int N, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
auto operator+(const fn_typelist<F, N, Ts...>&,
               const fn_typelist<F, N, Us...>&)
    -> fn_typelist<F, N, Ts..., Us...>;

template<typename... Ts, typename... Us>
auto operator+(typelist<Ts...>, typelist<Us...>)
    -> typelist<Ts..., Us...>;

template<typename T, typename... Us>
auto operator*(typelist<T>, typelist<Us...>)
    -> typelist<decltype(T{} + Us{})...>;

template<typename... Ts, typename TL>
auto operator^(typelist<Ts...>, TL tl)
    -> decltype(((typelist<Ts>{} * tl) + ...));

template<template<typename...> class F, typename... TLs>
using product_apply_t = decltype((layered<F, sizeof...(TLs)>(TLs{}) ^ ...));
```

And you use as

```
struct A0;
struct A1;
struct B0;
struct B1;
struct C0;
struct C1;
struct C2;

using t1 = typelist<A0, A1>;
using t2 = typelist<B0, B1>;
using t3 = typelist<C0, C1, C2>;

template<typename...>
struct fn {};

using p1 = product_apply_t<fn, t1, t2>;
using p2 = product_apply_t<fn, t1, t2, t3>;

using expect1 = typelist<fn<A0, B0>,
                         fn<A0, B1>,
                         fn<A1, B0>,
                         fn<A1, B1>>;

using expect2 = typelist<fn<A0, B0, C0>,
                         fn<A0, B0, C1>,
                         fn<A0, B0, C2>,
                         fn<A0, B1, C0>,
                         fn<A0, B1, C1>,
                         fn<A0, B1, C2>,
                         fn<A1, B0, C0>,
                         fn<A1, B0, C1>,
                         fn<A1, B0, C2>,
                         fn<A1, B1, C0>,
                         fn<A1, B1, C1>,
                         fn<A1, B1, C2>>;

static_assert(std::is_same_v<p1, expect1>);
static_assert(std::is_same_v<p2, expect2>);
```

Where `fn` can be swapped with any class template or template alias with suitable parameters.

This instantiates the first (n-1)-ary cartesian product then applies the provided meta function at the n-ary cartesian product. Not being familiar with compilers, I have no idea whether this confers any speedup in compilation times.

<sub>The implementation is arcane, if you want to ask about it, it likely means you should just stick with producing the pack and iterating. Or Boost.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

This is really the key insight in [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_productf_l) is that the question you're asking here is really the same question as the other questions.

`pack_product` is taking the cartesian product of a bunch of `pack`s and turning them all into `pack`s. So that's:

```cpp
template <class... Packs>
using pack_product = mp_product<pack, Packs...>;
```

`pack_product_apply` is the same thing. Or really, `pack_product` is a special case of `pack_product_apply` where the function you're applying to each list is `pack`:

```cpp
template <template <class...> class F, class... Packs>
using pack_product_apply = mp_product<F, Packs...>;
```

In other words, `pack_product_apply` *is* `mp_product`.

Now, your formulation is slightly different - you want to take a function that applies to a typelist (`F<L>`) instead of a function that applies to a pack (`F<Ts...>`). You can still do that, it's just that you need to pass something into `mp_product` that first groups the pack (i.e. first applies `pack` then `F`):

```cpp
template <template <class> class F, class... Packs>
using pack_product_apply = mp_product_q<mp_compose<pack, F>, Packs...>;
```